# Parse Server and mongodb issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I'm trying to setup a local install of a parse server for my express app. Here is what I have done:

```
npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
```

Then:

```
mongodb-runner start
```

That triggered this error:

```
  Starting a MongoDB deployment to test against...{ HTTPError: Response code 403 (Forbidden)
at EventEmitter.ee.on.res (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-runner/node_modules/got/index.js:250:24)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Immediate.setImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-runner/node_modules/got/index.js:99:8)
at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
name: 'HTTPError',
host: 'fastdl.mongodb.org',
hostname: 'fastdl.mongodb.org',
method: 'GET',
path: '/osx/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.0.3.tgz',
protocol: 'https:',
url:
'https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.0.3.tgz',
statusCode: 403,
statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
headers:
{ 'content-type': 'application/xml',
 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
 connection: 'close',
 date: 'Wed, 17 Oct 2018 18:38:43 GMT',
 server: 'AmazonS3',
 'x-cache': 'Error from cloudfront',
 via:
  '1.1 c743f1ce1ce65e454843328ae4e050a2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
 'x-amz-cf-id': 'eA7O6955PJVLdcvfXCAuTW3YOEGRoGcWGxGXRgAiPq8zbGFyBvug8Q==' } }
```

So instead of running mongodb locally I decided to create a cluster on mongodb.com. Then I tried running this command connecting to the cluster(of course I replaced the APP_ID, MASTER_KEY, and MONGODB_DATABASE_URI with the proper values):

```
parse-server --appId APP_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI MONGODB_DATABASE_URI
```

this is the error I got:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:225
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
at topology.connect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:412:16)
at ReplSet.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/replset.js:364:11)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at ReplSet.emit (events.js:182:13)
at ReplSet.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:631:23
at Server.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:357:9)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Server.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
```

I've been googling for so long and I can't figure this out. parse-server and mongodb are both completely up to date. Says parse-server is 3.0.0 and mongodb is 3.1.8

Answer (score 2):

It looks like mongodb-runner downloads some files from mongodb.org the first time and, according to [this thread](https://github.com/mongodb-js/runner/issues/128#issue-281329600), those links have changed for some versions. So try different mongo versions by setting then environmental var `MONGODB_VERSION` when running mongodb-runner:

```
MONGODB_VERSION=3.4.1 mongodb-runner
```