# mongodb-runner does not work(Response code 403)

Tags: node.js, linux, database, mongodb, parse-platform

So, I wanted to setup my mongoDB + Parse Server on my Kali Linux server. 
I followed the instructions on this Git-Repo: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server

When typing `npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner`
and `mongodb-runner start` I get the following log:

```
TPError: Response code 403 (Forbidden)
    at EventEmitter.ee.on.res (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-runner/node_modules/got/index.js:250:24)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Immediate.setImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-runner/node_modules/got/index.js:99:8)
    at runCallback (timers.js:694:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:665:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:647:5)
  name: 'HTTPError',
  host: 'fastdl.mongodb.org',
  hostname: 'fastdl.mongodb.org',
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-4.2.8.tgz',
  protocol: 'https:',
  url:
   'https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-4.2.8.tgz',                                           
  statusCode: 403,
  statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
  headers:
   { 'content-type': 'application/xml',
     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     connection: 'close',
     date: 'Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:17:34 GMT',
     server: 'AmazonS3',
     'x-cache': 'Error from cloudfront',
     via:
      '1.1 6b4954a8411e7b2a232537f8000c5c9d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',                                       
     'x-amz-cf-pop': 'FRA50-C1',
     'x-amz-cf-id': 'af_MHWQpIoBDL77-FBQHI5BED9OTX2E_kOGfHNg-LF9ujCGiCUGW2g==' } }                              
{ HTTPError: Response code 403 (Forbidden)
    at EventEmitter.ee.on.res (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-runner/node_modules/got/index.js:250:24)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Immediate.setImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-runner/node_modules/got/index.js:99:8)
    at runCallback (timers.js:694:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:665:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:647:5)
  name: 'HTTPError',
  host: 'fastdl.mongodb.org',
  hostname: 'fastdl.mongodb.org',
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-4.2.8.tgz',
  protocol: 'https:',
  url:
   'https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-4.2.8.tgz',                                           
  statusCode: 403,
  statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
  headers:
   { 'content-type': 'application/xml',
     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     connection: 'close',
     date: 'Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:17:34 GMT',
     server: 'AmazonS3',
     'x-cache': 'Error from cloudfront',
     via:
      '1.1 6b4954a8411e7b2a232537f8000c5c9d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',                                       
     'x-amz-cf-pop': 'FRA50-C1',
     'x-amz-cf-id': 'af_MHWQpIoBDL77-FBQHI5BED9OTX2E_kOGfHNg-LF9ujCGiCUGW2g==' } }
```

I dont know what to do. Did I install any wrong packages or something like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861652/parse-server-and-mongodb-issue check this answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse Server and mongodb issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861652/parse-server-and-mongodb-issue)